# JChannel constructor from JGroups very slow

Tags: java, windows, jgroups

I'm using JChannel from JGroups Library to communicate between applications.
Unfortunately, I notice that the constructor of JChannel and the connect call are really slow, about 4 secs for constructor and 5/6 secs for connect, using the default configuration (new JChannel() without params).
From GitHub I tryed various xml configurations from project repos, but no one seems to be significant faster than others.

```
channel = new JChannel(); //4 secs
channel.connect("MyCluster"); // 5-6 secs
```

I'm using Windows 10 with 4.0.19 Lib version (4.1.0+ versions are bugged in Windows, connect always fails).

Am I missing something? Why is so slow?

Thank you all.

Comment: The best way to figure out is to set logging level on `org.jgroups` to `TRACE` and observe what's happening underhood.

Comment: `tracert` (trace route) to see the network route and times / whether something weird happens. (Proxy?)

Answer (score 0):

The `connect()` call takes at least `GMS.join_timeout` ms for the first member, so you might want to copy udp.xml and modify that, plus pass the config to the JChannel constructor.

The creation of the channel should be fast! Perhaps your consrtuctor picks a different udp.xml from somewhere on the CLASSPATH?

I suggest run the java process in strace to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi, I changed GMS.join_timeout to 10 secs and the connect now takes 15-16 secs, so the xml config I use is correct. Default GMS.join_timeout is 10 msecs and in that way I get the 5-6 secs reported in my question.